# How to get the correct percentage from array of objects with aggregation pipeline

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have documents with an array of objects, and I need to do the following:

- Get the total points of member arrays. On the example, the 2 documents have a total of **5500** points.
- Next, get each document's members total points (for Josh it's **2000**, for Carl it's **3500**) and then compute what percent it is against the total points. Formula is: (members' points / total points) * 100 or **(2000 / 5500) * 100** for Josh.
- Finally, return the fields _id, leader, members' points, and percentage fields.

It should look something like below:

```
{
  _id: '00001',
  leader: "Josh",
  memberpoints: 2000,
  percentage: 36.3636
},
{
  _id: '00002',
  leader: "Carl",
  memberpoints: 3500,
  percentage: 63.6363
}
```

**These are the documents:**

```
[{
  "_id": { "$oid": "00001" },
  "leader": "Josh",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Person A",
      "points": 500
    },
    {
      "name": "Person B",
      "points": 500
    },
    {
      "name": "Person C",
      "points": 1000
    }]
  },
  {
  "_id": { "$oid": "00002" },
  "leader": "Carl",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Person D",
      "points": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Person E",
      "points": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Person F",
      "points": 1500
    }]
}]
```

But, I'm getting the wrong percentage because it seems like it's only getting a single object from the members array. It might have something to do with the $set part of my aggregation pipeline, specifically **[{ $divide: ["$members.points", "$total"] }, 100]**, but I'm not sure.

**Wrong percentage, should be 36.3636**

```
{
  _id: '00001',
  leader: "Josh",
  memberpoints: 2000,
  percentage: 18.1818
}
```

**Here is my MongoDB aggregation pipeline:**

```
db.users.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$members"}, 
{$setWindowFields: { output: { total: { $sum: "$members.points" }}}},
{$set: { percentage: { $multiply: [{ $divide: ["$members.points", "$total"] }, 100] }}},
{$group: { _id: "$_id", leader: {$first: "$leader"}, memberpoints: {$sum: "$members.points"}, percentage: {$first: "$percentage"}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct; just the order of `$set` and `$group` are reversed.  Here is a pipeline that produces the desired output with some comments:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$members"},

    // Great way to get the sum of everything in one pass without having
    // $group get in the way:
    {$setWindowFields: { output: { total: { $sum: "$members.points" }}}},

    // Basically home free.  Now re-group, summing the points.  The trick
    // here is to NOT lose the total amount; we will need it after we $sum.
    // We will call it 'percentage' here but only as a placeholder; we
    // will overwrite it with the REAL percentage in the next stage:
    {$group: {_id: "$_id",
              leader: {$first: "$leader"},
              memberpoints: {$sum: "$members.points"},
              percentage: {$first: "$total"}  // not really pct yet.
             }},

    // Now turn it into REAL pct.  The overwrite trick allows us to
    // to not have to unset a "temporary" total value.
    {$addFields: {
        percentage: {$multiply: [100, {$divide: ['$memberpoints', '$percentage']}]}
    }}
)]
```

Here is a fancy version that avoids the `$unwind` and re-`$group` by letting `$reduce` sum the memberpoints.  Eliminating `$unwind`/`$group` stages is not to be underestimated.  With a sample set of 1,000,000
docs, the solution above runs in 13128ms (avg); the more compact version below runs in just 6020ms -- TWICE as fast:

```
db.foo.aggregate([

    {$setWindowFields: {
        output: {
          total: { $sum: {$reduce: {
                         input: "$members",
                         initialValue: 0,
                         in: {$add: [ "$$value", "$$this.points"]}
                     }}
                 }
          }
    }}

    ,{$project: {
        _id: true,
        leader: true,
        memberpoints: {$sum:'$members.points'},
        percentage: {$multiply:[100,{$divide: [{$sum:'$members.points'},'$total']}]}
    }}

]);
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I used the first option for now, but will try the 2nd too.